# Not Null field with SonataAdmin Bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

Hi I have a problem with SonataAdminBundle.
I've created "Job" table in DB and I use in backend of my website.

When I insert data, I have an error with "not null" fields in my table Job.

For example I have "nb_comment" that is the number of comments of each job,so when I insert in backend all information about Job I don't use a NOT NULL field "nb_comment",and I have the following error :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nb_comment' cannot be null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in @ORM annotation **nullable=true**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

...

/**
 * @var integer $nb_comment
 * @ORM\Column(name="nb_comment", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $nb_comment;
```

or add Constraint validator with @Assert declaration and initialize in construct

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @var integer $nb_comment
 * @ORM\Column(name="nb_comment", type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $nb_comment;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->nb_comment = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem I think and it works for me. You have to initialize the variable `nb_comment` in the model with `null`, like this:

```
/**
 * @var integer $nb_comment
 */
private $nb_comment = null;
```